# Retornar toda página via cURL

Tags: php, libcurl, return

Preciso retornar uma página que está em *text/html*, porém está codificado com **zlib**, sim tentei decodificar mas sem chances, já que a função [zlib_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.zlib-decode.php), não está documentada então fiz buscas mas tudo sem sucesso, veja o retorno:

```
'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Language: pt-br
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2018 19:03:06 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400
Set-Cookie: alguns cookies'... (length=5280)
```

E aqui está meu `request`

```
function challenge($url) {
    $getCSRF = getCSRF();

    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($request, array(
        CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://www.url.com/' . $url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_COOKIE                  => $getCSRF->cookies,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => array(
            'accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'accept-language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        )
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);

    return $response;
}

var_dump(challenge('challenge/id/Fn0C4GsZjg/'));
```

Comment: Não seria mais simples alterar o `accept-encoding`? Talvez o servidor esteja compactando pelo fato de você mesmo ter pedido.

Comment: @Bacco já me sugeriram isso e não conseguir fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente torne `false` o `CURLOPT_HEADER`, assim:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
```

Pois se você tiver interesse nos headers você pode pegar usando `curl_getinfo` e talvez dividir a string (ou detectar quando ocorre a primeira vez duas quebras de linha seguidas), mas isto é outra situação.

Também é necessário detectar redirecionamentos para não cair em páginas vazia, então pode usar o:

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
```

E então por ultimo pode usar o `gzdecode`, assim:

```
function challenge($url) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    $getCSRF = getCSRF();

    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($request, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'https://www.url.com/' . $url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
            'accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'accept-language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        )
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($request);

    $resposta_http = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    //Qualquer código fora do range 200 e 299 provavelmente é pagina de erro
    if ($resposta_http < 200 && $resposta_http > 299) {
        $response = null;
    }

    curl_close($request);

    //Decodifica
    return $response ? gzdecode($response) : false;
}

var_dump(challenge('challenge/id/Fn0C4GsZjg/'));
```

Claro que o exemplo acima é se for Gzip, se for deflate terá que usar provavelmente o **`gzinflate`** (vou preparar um exemplo mais elaborado)

Outra situação que você pode resolver é simplesmente não enviar o `accept-encoding` como o @Bacco disse, assim:

```
curl_setopt_array($request, array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => 'https://www.url.com/' . $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
        'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    )
));
```

Se a página for leve realmente nem será necessário compactação no momento do download.

Comment: Obrigado. funcionou e não tenho nenhuma dúvida. Grato.

Comment: Seguinte mano tava funcionando retornei $response e dei um echo na função agora não tá pegando mais

Comment: @Guilherme com `var_dump` esta acusando FALSE ou NULL?

Comment: nada ele não me retorna nada

Comment: @Guilherme como assim nada, retorna então algo como `string(0) ""`? porque se for uma string vazia vai retorna isso, se for null retornar `NULL`, se for false vai retornar `bool(false)`, ou seja algo no var_dump tem que retornar, se não esta exibindo o var_dump é porque você fez algo de errado no script, pode estar dando erro 500, pode ser um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Ta tudo ok ta branco mesmo aoksoas mas to tentando aqui se funcionou a primeira vez tem que funcionar sempre kkk'

Comment: @Guilherme acho que vc esta fazendo confusão, não tem como var_dump retornar em branco, deve ser outro erro, se não esta exibindo o resultando do var_dump é que nem deve estar chegando no var_dump, faz o seguinte posta o seu código todo no http://pastebin.com e me manda que eu irei ver pra ti, deve ser alguma virgula ou `}` que vc esqueceu.

Comment: consegui, porem eu quero que mostre-me a página, eu dou um echo na função e no view-source do google chrome ta lá o código da página mas sem ser no viewsource nao aparece nada. alias tem sim porém não mostra a pagina

Comment: @Guilherme posta o código no pastebin, pois o problema parece ser outra coisa não relacionada.